# Passing "-J-Duser.language" into javac through ant to ensure compilation errors are reported in the correct language

Tags: ant, javac

My PC is currently set up as Japanese for testing purposes. If my java project has a compilation error the message is reported in Japanese.

e.g.
Compiling 1 source file to [...directory...]
[...class...].java:172: シンボルを見つけられません。

I would prefer to see the errors in english.

Without using ant the fix for this is to use 
    javac -J-Duser.language=en [..java files...]
which makes javac give english error messages (the -J tells javac to pass the rest of the argument to java)

My question is: how do I pass this to ant 
[editted to remove options I tried that didn't work]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a `<compilerarg>` to your `<javac>` call. For example:

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" fork="true">
    <compilerarg value="-J-Duser.language=en"/>
    <compilerarg value="-J-Duser.country=GB"/>
</javac>
```

**EDIT** Fixed the arg values. Also, this only works if the compiler is forked; I updated the example to reflect that.