# How to set default language for java keytool?

Tags: java, ssl, keyboard, keytool

I use Windows OS with English language and US keyboard setting. I use this command to generate keystore. It works fine.

```
C:\java6\jre\bin\keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias mykey -validity 3652 -keystore C:\mykeystore -storepass 111111111 < data.txt
```

The data.txt

```
My name
My org unit
My org
My city
My state
ch
yes
```

However, this program cannot work normally on Windows with German language and keyboard setting. I must change the word "**yes**"" to "**ja**" in data.txt to make it works.

It isn't good to modify the data.txt.

Is there any way to set English as default language for keytool?

Comment: I found out that we can force Java to use English as default language by adding `-J"-Duser.language=en"`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In a nutshell you must pass the `-Duser.language=en` option to the Java machine. I know of two ways to do this:

1. For just one invocation, specify the `-J-Duser.language=en` option on the `keytool` command line, e.g.

   ```
   keytool -J-Duser.language=en -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias mykey -validity 3652 -keystore C:\mykeystore -storepass 111111111 < data.txt
   ```

   See also [SO: Forcing the use of english in JDK7 tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6217395/213376)
2. To change Java language globally, set the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable to have the `-Duser.language=en` value.

Comment: Thanks, I found it :)

Comment: The `-J-Duser.language=en` parameter does not seem to be understood by keytool.exe on Windows. The approach via `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` however works fine.