# Git Bash Terminal Encoding Issue with Java

Tags: java, character-encoding, windows-10, git-bash

Hi so I am on Win10 and Git 2.35.1.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.35.1.windows.1
```

I think my Git Bash terminal has some encoding issues.
For example if I type `java` the message I got is all mojibake.

(I am not sure why my Java is printing in another language other than English honestly. I did not configure anything special when I install JRE or JDK.)

```
$ java
▒÷▒: java [-options] class [args...]
           (ִ▒▒▒▒)
   ▒▒  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (ִ▒▒ jar ▒ļ▒)
▒▒▒▒ѡ▒▒▒▒▒:
    -d32          ʹ▒▒ 32 λ▒▒▒▒ģ▒▒ (▒▒▒▒▒▒▒)
    -d64          ʹ▒▒ 64 λ▒▒▒▒ģ▒▒ (▒▒▒▒▒▒▒)
    -client       ѡ▒▒ "client" VM
    -server       ѡ▒▒ "server" VM
                  Ĭ▒▒ VM ▒▒ client.
```

My locale is UTF-8 though:

```
$ locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```

And, when using commands like `echo`, UTF-8 characters are correctly displayed though:

```
$ echo 中文中文
中文中文
```

I tried various methods like `git config --global i18n.logOutputEncoding utf-8` and `setx LC_ALL C.UTF-8` but `java` command still prints a mess.

What is the problem?

Is `java` command using some other encoding all together, not UTF-8?

Comment: You can switch locale permanently as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217297/forcing-the-use-of-english-in-jdk7-tools

Comment: Our use terminal emulator that better handles utf8

Comment: Can you paste first line of `java |& xxd` ?

Comment: @Philippe `00000000: d3c3 b7a8 a3ba 6a61 7661 205b 6f70 7469  ......java [opti`

Comment: @user16320675 On Windows CMD java prints Chinese Characters correctly. `C:\Windows\System32>java
用法：java [options] <主类> [args...]
           （执行类）
   或  java [options] -jar <jar 文件> [args...]
           （执行 jar 文件）` and so on. Only Git Bash screws up the encoding.

Comment: @orhtej2 Nice. Found a solution that works by following your link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22610609/6309), if this works:

```
java -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US

java -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -XshowSettings -version
```

The second command would show the current settings.

If that work, you can set those options through the environment variable [`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html).
Although, since JDK9+, [`JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52989562/6309) is a valid alternative.

Comment: Not working.
The first line seems to be an incorrect usage of `java` command as when I type it into bash, it prints the help message of `java` command.

Comment: That seems expected, since the java command is not followed by any other subcommands. Does it print the help message entirety in English though? Or, as in your question, does it still mix languages?

Comment: Yes. If I append `-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US` to a java command then the log will be printed in English. However you must do this everytime.

Comment: @LongYu Excellent, I was waiting that confirmation to suggest `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Following instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217297/forcing-the-use-of-english-in-jdk7-tools), I found a permanent fix: `REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS /d -Duser.language=en /t REG_SZ /f` and restart computer.

And now when I type `java`

```
$ java
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.language=en
Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [options] -jar <jarfile> [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
   or  java [options] -m <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
...
```