# How to change the display language of javac to English?

Tags: java

I'm using Windows 8 with Japanese language. I installed the JDK SE8, and the javac compiler messages are all in Japanese.

I tried changing the non-unicode system locale setting to English, restarted, and reinstalled the JDK, as suggested in similar questions, but now javac just displays a bunch of question marks in the command prompt. How can I change the output to English?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try passing this argument: `-J-Duser.language=en`. See this post: [Passing "-J-Duser.language" into javac through ant to ensure compilation errors are reported in the correct language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920763/passing-j-duser-language-into-javac-through-ant-to-ensure-compilation-errors)

Comment: Thank you, although it would be nice to have a permanent solution, that works great as a workaround!

Comment: To set it permanently for all users: REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS /d -Duser.language=en /t REG_SZ /f

Comment: If anyone wants to set manually and permanently on Windows, try setting an environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` whose value is `-Duser.language=en`. (To do so, `Win + R` to run `sysdm.cpl`, then `advanced`, then `environment variables`.) It works on my side. On command line,`javac` displays `Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.language=en` every time it runs.