# Java - Error message showing question marks instead of characters

Tags: java

```
$ javac Increment.java
```

Output:

```
Increment.java:6: ??: ?????
    System.out.println(++a++);
                          ^
  ??: ??
  ??:    ?
1 ???
```

here is the code

```
class Increment{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 5;


    System.out.println(++a++);
  }
}
```

Does any one know what may be happening and how to fix it?
Increment is just a class for testing so that a error will appear.
I am running it in git-bash terminal, but I have tried it in cygwin terminal and windows's terminal as well.
character-set is UTF-8.

Comment: Can you post the source code that is causing this?

Comment: I think you’ll need to provide some more information. Perhaps starting with the code of `Increment`.

Comment: What you are running this command in will have an encoding, is it some kind of shell?

Comment: sorry, now it is added

Comment: Still not sufficient, add code form increment class

Comment: @ Shivaraj sure

Comment: What is that ++ before and after a, are you trying to increment a?

Comment: Why do you use git-bash instead of a regular shell, or even better, an IDE ?

Comment: @Shivaraj I did that because I want an error will appear so that we can see the error message is  not displaying correctly

Comment: @Benoit I am new to programming and my teacher suggested me not to use an IDE

Comment: As far as I can see on my host, the error message does not even contain special characters. This should work as well for ASCII, UTF-8 or ISO8859 charsets. Something looks really broken with your terminal.

Comment: OK @Kallzvx but why specifically git-bash ? Why not the default terminal under Windows ?

Comment: @ Benoit I am more familiar with Bash, and it does not work in window's terminal as well, sorry for not adding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have a national locale set up (e.g. Russian, Chinese or anything else) that makes the Java compiler to return nationalized error messages, but your terminal (cygwin) does not support the UTF-8 output or your system does not support UTF-8 locale.

As the quickest work-around you could switch java compiler to [provide error messages in English](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23749714/2288384):

```
$ javac -J-Duser.language=en Increment.java
```