# How to set the display language of javac 20?

Tags: java, javac

Having a computer with the system property *user.language* set to `de`, I would like to see the compiler messages in English.
In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749714/how-to-change-the-display-language-of-javac-to-english) two methods are proposed for java8:

1. to use the `-Duser.language=en` switch on the command line, but `-D` isn't shown in the list of available switches for javac 20 any more.
2. to set an environment variable by the name JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS under Windows. This, however, sets both java and javac to the desired language, but I would like only the compiler language to be changed.

### Edit

The above mentioned post also tells trying `-J-Duser.language=en`
which is rejected at my site with `Fehler: Ungültiges Kennzeichen: .language=en` which might read in English "Error: Invalid token/indicator:  .language=en"

### Edit 2

I accepted DuncG's answer, but the actual solution is in his comment to the original question. Thank you.

Comment: That error looks like somehow it has read whitespace after `user` and before `.language=en` - perhaps try `javac '-J-Duser.language=en' xyz.java` (double quoted in Windows, single in GNU/Linux).

Comment: Both with double quotes and single quote it works on windows. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my JDK installation the `-J` flag can be used, though this does not work for all language codes:

```
C:\dev>javac -J-Duser.language=de ayx.java
Fehler: Datei nicht gefunden: ayx.java
Verwendung: javac <Optionen> <Quelldateien>
Mit --help können Sie eine Liste der möglichen Optionen aufrufen

C:\dev>javac -J-Duser.language=en ayx.java
error: file not found: ayx.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

**EDIT**

The above works on Linux or Windows CMD, but Windows Powershell reports an error as appears to process the single  parameter `-J-Duser.language=de` as two parameters `-J-Duser` then `.language=de`. For Powershell just add quotes to handle as single parameter value:

```
PS C:\dev> javac -J-Duser.language=de xyz.java
error: invalid flag: .language=de
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options

PS C:\dev> javac "-J-Duser.language=de" xyz.java
Fehler: Datei nicht gefunden: xyz.java
Verwendung: javac <Optionen> <Quelldateien>
Mit --help können Sie eine Liste der möglichen Optionen aufrufen
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should have mentioned this possibility, too, and edited my post. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the JDK20 module `jdk.compiler` in good IDE or src.zip. For my OpenJDK20 there are language packs for `zh`, `ja`, `de` in package `com.sun.tools.javac.resource` and other `*.resource` folders and `en` is the default inside `javac.java`