# Passing “-J-Duser.language” to gradle not working

Tags: gradle, javac

I want to have English messages when compiling.

Following this [post](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/passing_arguments_to_compiler_and_javadoc) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920763/passing-j-duser-language-into-javac-through-ant-to-ensure-compilation-errors), I added the following to my `build.gradle`

```
compileJava {
  options.compilerArgs << '-J-Duser.language=en'
  options.fork = true
  options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'
}
```

But I get ([] is my translation, not official)

```
javac: 无效的标记[invalid flags]:  -J-Duser.language=en
用法[usage]: javac <options> <source files>
-help 用于列出可能的选项[for possible options]
```

In `cmd`, a simple `javac -J-Duser.language=en` do gives me English messages.

My question:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I make gradle show the exact `javac` command used when compiling?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `-J`, passing the flag to `options.forkOptions.jvmArgs` should work:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.jvmArgs += ["-Duser.language=en"]
}
```