# How to change the display language of javac in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I would like to set javac compile option as "-J-Duser.language=en" in gradle.

my question is pretty mach same as [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920763/passing-j-duser-language-into-javac-through-ant-to-ensure-compilation-errors)

so i tried following code:

```
project.tasks.withType(JavaCompile.class) {
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.jvmArgs = ["-J-Duser.language=en"]
    ...
}
```

Then gradle return following error message

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: -J-Duser.language=en
```

I believe that I am doing something wrong. How can I change the output to English in gradle plugin?

ADD:
I also tried following code

```
project.tasks.withType(JavaCompile.class) {
    options.compilerArgs << '-J-Duser.language=en'
    ... 
}
```

then, gradle returns this error code:

```
    > Cannot specify -J flags via `CompileOptions.compilerArgs`. 
Use the `CompileOptions.forkOptions.jvmArgs` property instead.
```

Comment: I don't use gradle, but you are putting the _compiler_ option `-J-Duser.language=en` to something called "jvmArgs". That doesn't look right. The JVM option is just `-Duser.language=en`, or you can set [`compileArgs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593500/how-can-i-set-the-compileoptions-for-my-gradle-java-plugin) instead.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for responding. As I add some information the question, using options.compilerArgs did not work. and error message suggest to use forkOptions.jvmArgs. Do I missed something else?

Comment: How about just specifying `-Duser.language=en`, without `-J`, as `jvmArgs`?

Comment: @Sweep thanks again. it worked! would you write an answer? or should I write down an answer?

Answer (score 0):

What the `-J` option for the Java compiler does, is it sends the option after it to the JVM ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)):

> -J_option_
>
> Passes `option` to the Java Virtual Machine (JVM), where option is one of the options described on the reference page for the Java launcher. For example, `-J-Xms48m` sets the startup memory to 48 MB.

But here you are passing JVM options, not compiler options, so you don't need the `-J`, and can just pass `-Duser.language=en` directly. As you have found out, Gradle even disallows you to pass JVM options indirectly via `-J`.